# "hard-disk not found" windows XP installation

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-workstation, windows-installation

Installing windows XP Professional 64 bit on a virtual machine using VMware Workstation V9

When installing Windows XP by using the IMG file I have of the XP Installation disk mounted as a CD disk.

[image: xp cannot find hard-disk]

There are numerous articles covering this, but no apparent consensus on what exactly should be done to solve it. Many of the googled answers point to XP's flaky SCSI support and recommend the installation of SCSI drivers through the mounting of a floppy image (http://download3.vmware.com/software/vmscsi-1.2.0.4.flp). This didn't work for me, despite getting Windows xp to recognise the image. Upon getting a confirmation of the install and an installation welcome screen, the exact same hard-disk error displayed, preventing any further progress.

[image: scsi driver install xp]

Some guides discussing the problem mention how [this may not always work](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2012/05/solving-error-vmware-workstation-setup-windows-xp-setup-did-not-find-any-hard-disk-drives-installed-in-your-computer/) and a somewhat home-brewed patch may be required. Other sources have stated that a LSILogic Driver may be required. Other guides such as [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_rY8HLdNtg), despite being very detailed, give distinctly incorrect advice (in particular, suggesting that using an earlier version of Workstation or choosing IDE over SCSI as an install parameter (if the machine does not support such) will overcome this problem.

I have been, if anything, left more confused. :/

**NOTE:** Windows XP installs fine on quick install, it is merely on custom installation that this error is triggered.

Comment: not need vmware scsi driver ... wait 2 hour I test it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vmware 9 Windows XP 64 VM

not need add driver.

[image: Vmware 9 Windows XP 64 VM]

CD: AMD64\eula.txt

EULAID:WS03SP1_RM.0_PX64_RTL_EN

remove not need device

[image: device settings]

setup SCSI HDD VMWare

[image: SCSI HDD VMWare]

Set Microsoft Windows 64

Windows XP Professional x64 Edition.vmx:

guestOS = "winxppro-64"

[image: Set Microsoft Windows 64]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply, but I'm finding it slightly hard to follow. Is there something other than the driver that I need to do?

Comment: Select Windows XP 64. I add it in my answer + 10 min.

Comment: if need add VM template file + winnt.sif